# 500 error: im getting and not able to retrieve data

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Null value was assigned to a property `[class com.crisil.masters.domain.FundsHolidayMaster.bse]` of primitive type setter of `com.crisil.masters.domain.FundsHolidayMaster.bse;` nested

> exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was
>   assigned to a property

[class com.crisil.masters.domain.FundsHolidayMaster.bse] of `primitive` type setter of com.crisil.masters.domain.FundsHolidayMaster.bse

Comment: You will need to post some code. With a description like that, its very difficult to help u.

Comment: Without any code and detailed description of the problem, no one can help you here.Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to understand how to ask a good question on stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your property in `FundsHolidayMaster` is primitive type so that it can not be `null`. You should change it to Reference type (for example `int` to `Integer`) or find the null record and correct it if it's not supposed to be.

Comment: thanks, .................i deleted the null values in DATABASE n it worked out ......

Comment: If my answer resolved your problem, please mark it as correct answer. Thanks @SaiShashank